# Halo does not stick to particle system but fills the whole domain object

Tags: rendering, particles, shaders

Please find attached my [.blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rFM25CKF6-AT_hlCef_HF-jasTyyZhwO/view?usp=sharing)

I'm learning blender and at the moment I was playing around with the Halo effect and found several tuts explaining the same for version v2.9+

1. Use an emitter object where you want the Halo effect around.
2. Assign the particles system
3. Use a domain object that contains the emitter and its particles.
4. Use **Point density** node --> density output as input to --->
5. Strength input of **Emission** node and put that output to input of volume of the domain

But I just cant get it up and running. I see the particles and I see my domain cube is glooming like hell, but no matter what I change or play around with all the possible settings. The halos will never stick/substitute the particles of the emitter.

[image]

Can anybody have a look into my .blend file?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It appears to me like currently the point density node does not work with Eevee.  If you change the render engine to Cycles it should work as expected.  I however know very little about Eevee so I suppose there's a chance it just requires a different setup.

Comment: I should have told that I already researched over 4 hours about this and trial and error anything I could find and mind of.Unfortunately switching between EEVE and Cycles and playing around with all the rendersettings didnt chance anything :-(